# Android ListView not scrolling on S3 mini

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollable

we developed an Android app which contains several listviews. They work fine one most phones, like Samsung S3 neo, Galaxy S5, some older Samsung Galaxy phone, but not on the Samsung S3 mini.

The code for one of the listviews is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/deviceParameters_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/deviceParameters_listview"
        style="@style/listview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The style definition:

```
<style name="listview">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/listview_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/listview_padding_right</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/capacity_blue</item>
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

Any idea why it isn't working on the S3 mini? Might there be some app or setting that prevents the listviews from being scrollable?

Comment: try removing the overscrollmode set to "never" in the style, not sure but that's the only thing that could avoid listview from scrolling in your code,   the list is not visible but I guess that's just part of your code and you're handling it: android:visibility="gone"

Comment: @labreu Yeah visibility.gone is handled by the code, will try your suggestion :)

Comment: What version of Android is on your S3 mini. Does all your testing phones have the same version ?

Comment: @HpTerm They all have different versions, ranging from 4.1 to 5.0, but this should be basic listview functionality, so I am rather confused :)

Comment: Yes it's basic listview functionality, but we are searching a solution to your problem that's why I ask that, moreover if the same code work on other devices, the only reason that comes to my mind is android versions. What version is on the S3 mini ? Did you try to remove the overScrollMode as @labreu said ?